# How to not set focus to CrystalReportViewer automatically?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, crystal-reports

There is a problem i am facing, whenever I am setting the ReportSource property of CrystalReportViewer, the CrystalReportViewer control automatically steals focus from other controls. Like lets say I have a button I press which has the code to show the report in the report viewer, after this code is done, the CrystalReportViewer1 will have focus now. I dont want this to happen, I want the button to retain the focus. Also setting the focus back to the button is not possible gracefully as the time the CrystalReportViewer1 takes to render the report and set focus to itself is unpredictable, and there are no straight ways to know for sure when CR viewer is done doing its thing, there are some shortcuts/hacks which I dont want to follow.

I am using windows forms visual studio 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Properties of CrystalReportViewer and set

```
initialFocus = ParameteralPanel.
```

Please find Image here:

[image]

Comment: this changes the behavior, but doesnt work everytime somehow, i have 4 textboxes each of which on focus lost have to update/refresh the CR Viewer, rarely the focus from first tb to the second is successful, so this is not working for me. CR viewer takes quite some time to refresh, like around 1+ to 3 or so seconds, and by the time it is done the focus is never set on the second tb, well it did once or so but not after that.

Comment: makes me think, what kind of a Control is this, you update it and it says "give me the focus I am taking it", for absolutely no reason!